Folium LayerControl: Combine popup info for overlapping geometries
I am using Folium's LayerControl on a map of the US states, where each row is a ballot measure with description column and a list-like tags column.
I want the user to be able to filter the measures by topic, where the popup shows ALL the measures matching the selected tags. Right now, the map only shows a popup with Description for one ballot measure at a time, because the geometries are overlapping. Here is the current map with an example of what I mean:
The map right now - where Colorado (selected) has matching ballot measures for all 3 selected topics but only shows one popup at a time
My question: How to dynamically update the popup by combining all the row data that matches the selected tags?
Here is a small portion of my geodataframe:



NAME
Title
Description
tags
geometry




Alaska
Ballot Measure 1
Increase the state's minimum wage to $15 per h...
[Minimum wage]
MULTIPOLYGON (((-15108567.654 8339788.089, -15...


Arkansas
Issue 1
Allow proceeds from the state lottery to fund ...
[Education, Gambling]
POLYGON ((-10515267.713 4101325.818, -10515269...


Arkansas
Issue 2
Repeal the authorization for a casino license ...
[]
POLYGON ((-10515267.713 4101325.818, -10515269...


Arizona
Proposition 138
Allow for tipped workers to be paid 25% less p...
[Tips, Minimum wage]
POLYGON ((-12761162.105 4147165.875, -12761214...


Arizona
Proposition 139
Provide for a state constitutional right to ab...
[Abortion]
POLYGON ((-12761162.105 4147165.875, -12761214...


Arizona
Proposition 313
Require that anyone convicted of child sex tra...
[Crime]
POLYGON ((-12761162.105 4147165.875, -12761214...


Arizona
Proposition 314
Provide for several changes to criminal and im...
[Crime, Immigration]
POLYGON ((-12761162.105 4147165.875, -12761214...


Arizona
Proposition 315
Prohibit a proposed rule from becoming effecti...
[]
POLYGON ((-12761162.105 4147165.875, -12761214...


California
Proposition 2
Issue $10 billion in bonds to fund constructio...
[Education]
MULTIPOLYGON (((-13060108.516 3854208.959, -13...



Here is the code used to make the map pictured above:
tagnames = ['Abortion','Tips','Crime','Immigration','Education','Housing','Healthcare','Environment','Infrastructure','Energy','Veterans','Gay marriage','Hunting','Gambling','Guns','Marijuana','Psychedelics','Ranked-choice voting','Minimum wage']

m = folium.Map(location=[40, -97], zoom_start=4, tiles="CartoDB positron", scrollWheelZoom=False)

#For loop creates separate GeoJson layer for each filter category
d={}
for count, name in enumerate(tagnames, start=1):
    d[f'{name}'] = gdf[gdf['tags'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list) and f'{name}' in x)]
    d[f'group{count}'] = folium.FeatureGroup(f'{name}', show=False).add_to(m)
    folium.GeoJson(d[f'{name}'],
                   tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(['NAME'], labels=False),
                   popup=folium.GeoJsonPopup(['Description'], labels=False)
                   ).add_to(d[f'group{count}'])

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)

m

If I can do this using python only, that would be the best solution. I have tried to insert javascript to solve this but am not very familiar with the language.
Thank you!
